# Interface with non-copyable features

Tags: c++, visual-c++, interface

I am trying to implement a logging factory and I have used an interface so that I can swap loggers whenever I like.

Here is the interface

```
class ILogger
{
public:

    //Only allow string input. The entire ARC is going to be non-unicode.
    virtual void log(std::string message, eLogLevel level=DEBUG) = 0;

protected:
    virtual ~ILogger(void){};


private:
    // No one can create an ILogger as it is abstract but should also
    // disallow copying... why copy a logger? Only one per file. Besides want to 
    // force people to use the factory.
    /*ILogger(const ILogger&);
    ILogger& operator=(const ILogger&);*/ // REMOVED THIS BECAUSE OF ERROR

};
```

And here is a derived class (header)

```
class GenericLoggerImpl :
    public ILogger
{
public:
    virtual ~GenericLoggerImpl(void);
    virtual void log(std::string message, eLogLevel level=DEBUG);

private:
    GenericLoggerImpl(void); //USE THE FACTORY
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<GenericLogger> pImpl; //This is the implementation
    friend class LoggerFactory; // class LoggerFactory can now build these
};
```

And CPP

```
GenericLoggerImpl::GenericLoggerImpl(void):pImpl()
{
    pImpl = std::tr1::shared_ptr<GenericLogger> (new GenericLogger()); //This is the implementation
}

GenericLoggerImpl::~GenericLoggerImpl(void)
{
}

void GenericLoggerImpl::log(std::string message, eLogLevel level)
{
    pImpl->logMsg(message.c_str(),level);
}
```

Now here is the problem. See in the ILogger interface, I have commented out a private section of code? Well that is intended to stop anyone copying an ILogger derived class (like boost::noncopyable does). This makes sense (to me anyway) as it disallows separate instances of loggers from accessing the same file, and make the user go through my handy LoggerFactory.

When these lines are included then I get the following error:

> genericloggerimpl.cpp(6) : error C2512: 'ILogger' : no appropriate default constructor available

What is that about? I do not want these objects to be copyable. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you saved it before compiling it again? And I don't understand in your code what part is actually making the call to construct the `ILogger` (sub) object? What does the class `GenericLogger` look like?

Comment: @Mahesh - I have a separate LoggerFactory object that offers a number of creator functions. You can see that it is a friend of the implementation class GenericLoggerImpl. 
GenericLogger is a logging class, it is quite complicated. You can think of GenericLoggerImpl as acting like an adapter to that class. Or in other terms, GenericLoggerImpl is an ILogger, implemented in terms of GenericLogger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of **any** user-defined constructor (which includes a copy-constructor) will prevent the compiler from generating a default-constructor. Your subclass `GenericLogger` relies on the existence of a default-constructor for `ILogger` (it is implicitly called, since it is not specified otherwise in the initialization-list of the constructor of `GenericLogger`), hence the error.

To fix the problem, simple declare a protected trivial default constructor for `ILogger`:

```
ILogger() {}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. The simplest fixes are always the best ones :)

Comment: @Dennis: Another hint: If you have access to Boost, you can use [`boost::noncopyable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable) to express that an object is non-copyable. It's a bit more explicit and thus cleaner.

Comment: Good point. I'll have to check the project repository to see if noncopyable is already in there.

Answer (score 1):

You may inherit from following class to disable copying for any class you want to protect:

```
class no_copy
{
protected:
    // For derived class. Protected just to avoid direct instantiation of this class
    no_copy(){}

private:    
    no_copy(const no_copy&);
    void operator =(const no_copy&);
};
```

Example:

```
class MyClass:public no_copy
{
};
```

Error:

```
MyClass cls1;
MyClass cls2(cls1); // Error
cls2 = cls1; // Error
```